# How can we trigger gitlab-ci before pushing to repository?

Tags: devops, gitlab-ci, hook, push

I want to implement pre-receive hooks on the GitLab server side but we don't have access to the file system. Is there any way I can handle it with GitLab-ci? I want to get control over what can and can't be pushed to the repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to implement pre-recieve hooks in gitLab but that comes when we have access to file system. For now, I have added gitlab-ci that will check on every merge request on protected branches and let all developers push to temp branches.

Comment: So gateway branch instead of gateway repository. Good call. That should work too.

Answer (score 2):

One possible workaround would be for developers to:

- push to a gateway repository
- pull from an official one.

(both on GitLab)

You can then associate a job on the first one, `on push:`, in order to validate what has been pushed.
If validated, the job push the commit to the second official repository.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Is there any way we can trigger gitlab-ci on push event and based on some condition we can reject the commit?

Comment: @wajahatlateef The reject the commit part would be "not pushing the received commit to the second repository". But again, the all process is not akin to a *pre*-receive hook. The commit has been received.